# Attempted ubuntu 14.04 install, windows 8 vanished

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, resolution, hp

so I'm very new to Ubuntu. While trying to install it on my HP pavilion 17 it froze causing me to do a reboot. When I rebooted Windows 8 has vanished and I can only boot Ubuntu, which wouldn't be a problem but the screen resolution is now very off and everything looks pixelized.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your installation may hae simply diabled your ability to bot to Windows. Insert any windows recovery disk or Windows installation disk you have lying around and let it repair it's boot. After you regain access to your windows, do the Ubuntu installation again overwriting your existing installation (It may be corrupt).